# How to interact with an element that is hidden using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Element properties:-**

```
 <textarea id="txtSuffixTitle" class="form-control" tabindex="3" rows="2" placeholder="Suffix Title" name="txtSuffixTitle" maxlength="50" cols="20" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">Suffix Title </textarea>
```

**Selenium Code:-**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtSuffixTitle")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("txtSuffixTitle")).sendKeys("Mr.");
```

**Error:-**

*Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only*

I found the below solution in one of the post. I am able to interact with element with this but it is breaking the UI.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("txtSuffixTitle"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.display='inline'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, elem);
```

Could someone please suggest ? I can type it manually but due to the style property i.e. style="display: none; visibility: hidden; automation is unable to interact.

Comment: doesn't the fact that it's hidden suggest that your test should navigate the document and perform the neccesary validations in order to make this element visible??

Comment: There is no validations involve here. Development team intentionally added this code to fix some Spell check issues in IE9.

Comment: If a user cant do it, Selenium also wont be able to do it. What the point of doing something in test which user can't do? You can use some Javascript hack to do it but better you should revisit your tests.

Comment: Text area is not hidden. I can type it manually but the style property is style="display: none; visibility: hidden; & due to this, automation is unable to type.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is hidden, you can't interact through selenium. But with the javascript executor, you should be able to do something like:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('txtSuffixTitle').innerText = 'Mr.'");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Though the test is getting passed with this code but values are not getting entered in those text boxes using innerText.

Comment: Are you sure of that? the text area is hidden.

Comment: Text area is not hidden. I can type it manually but the style property is style="display: none; visibility: hidden;

I think due to this automation is unable to interact with that element.